# How can I use eww as a renderer for mu4e?

Tags: mu4e, eww

Emacs 24.4 came with native eww browser.
What is the proper way to use eww as a renderer for mu4e messages?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`eww` is basically an interactive wrapper around the `shr` package, which renders HTML as Emacs text (the actual HTML parsing is done by the `libxml` package). You can use it in `mu4e` by setting `mu4e-html2text-command` to a simple custom function:

```
(defun my-render-html-message ()
  (let ((dom (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))))
    (erase-buffer)
    (shr-insert-document dom)
    (goto-char (point-min))))

(setq mu4e-html2text-command 'my-render-html-message)
```

The git version of `mu4e` includes this built-in as `mu4e-shr2text`, and it can be set like so:

```
(require 'mu4e-contrib) 
(setq mu4e-html2text-command 'mu4e-shr2text)
```

Comment: `mu4e-shr2text` do not display images :(

Comment: @shackra For displaying html that comes from e-mail that's actually a good thing. I'm not sure if there's a key for toggling that, but even with that it should default to not showing images. That's, of course, regarding loading images from remote URIs, local images should be shown by default.